# No module named numpy, when installing pybdf

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

Deploying flask app on azure. Here is my requirements.txt

```
appdirs==1.4.3
biosppy==0.6.1
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
h5py==2.10.0
heartpy==1.2.7
hrv-analysis==1.0.4
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
lockfile==0.12.2
matplotlib==3.2.0
msgpack==0.6.2
mtcnn==0.1.0
packaging==20.3
pandas==1.0.5
pep517==0.8.2
plotly==4.8.2
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scikit-posthocs==0.6.4
scikit-video==1.1.11
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
statsmodels==0.11.1
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
opencv-python
tensorflow==2.2.0
numpy
tables==3.6.1
orange3==3.27.1
pybdf
```

I have even added a pip isntall numpy before pip install -r requirements in the .yaml file.
Any help would be appreciated, and if not here an alternate method to deploy my flask app? if possible!

Comment: Are you getting an error and if so could include?

Comment: You need run `apt-get install cmake gfortran` first, it will help you.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove pybdf in the requirements.txt file. Manually install pybdf in webssh, and then test.**

Open SSH , install the package manually before publishing the program.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cmake gfortran
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
pip install pybdf
```

[image]